# Need power supply with +24v, 0v, -24v that provides min 10A

Tags: power-supply, power, dual

For my project, I need a power supply with +24v, 0v, -24v that provides minimum of 10A...

- Need to have two loads (one positive 24v & 0 and one negative -24v & 0) need to have common point(0v)
- The load between 24v to 0 and 0 and -24 vary dynamically...
- The total current capacity should be 10a
- The solution need to be sleek and cost effective

I am unable find any power supplies in the market(India)... When I try to design my own using LM7824/7924 the maximum current is limited to 1.5A

Do we have any solution to this issue? Thanks

Comment: You're not finding it because you're probably looking on Amazon (or whatever..) Go to a professional class supplier, you'll find many supplies that would work. Whether you can afford it is a different question. e.g. https://www.bkprecision.com/products/power-supplies

Comment: I believe two of these might do the trick: https://www.mornsun-power.com/html/pdf/LMF320-23B24.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, the best option is to have some psu's in series to, ideally generate 24,0,"-24". But usually that's a very bad idea unless the manufacter allows such configuration.
My bet will be on using Batteries!, yeah, Two 24V lithium batteries will do the trick pretty easily... in series configuration, you could even use car batteries (if avalible) for this purpouse.
The no- so direct answer will be to use a dual buck converter configuration(24,0,24)... but that will be a lot more complex, and you may have problems with the ripple if the applications requires noise-free DC

Comment: Thanks... Yes... The solution will be expensive and bulky

Answer (score 0):

Connect two 24v/10A power suplies in series, but be sure manufacture of those PSU allow such a connection.

Comment: Thanks... But for a solution, having two PS will be bulky